# Crash on iOS when system purges memory and closes a UIViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, uiviewcontroller, crash, low-memory

My application is crashing when one of the views is purged from memory because of low-memory condition. At least this is what I understand from the crashlog. It happens on numerous screens but only when opening a Facebook dialog (using the Facebook SDK). Basically, looks like the system sometimes runs out of memory when we need to present a Facebook dialog (e.g. to let user post something on the Facebook timeline).

```
Date/Time: 2012-03-14 19:47:33.819 +0000
OS Version: iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version: 104
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x30000008
Crashed Thread: 0
Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x30f2bf78 objc_msgSend + 16
1 MyApp 0x00003c0e -LTBaseViewController viewDidUnload (LTBaseViewController.m:145)
2 MyApp 0x00004ea2 -LTBaseTableViewController viewDidUnload (LTBaseTableViewController.m:90)
3 UIKit 0x33766bd8 -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] + 244
4 UIKit 0x338ae492 -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 58
5 Foundation 0x3071a4f8 __57-NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:_block_invoke_0 + 12
6 CoreFoundation 0x30e95540 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 64
7 CoreFoundation 0x30e21090 _CFXNotificationPost + 1400
8 Foundation 0x3068e3e4 -NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo: + 60
9 Foundation 0x3068fc14 -NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object: + 24
10 UIKit 0x3387926a -UIApplication _performMemoryWarning + 74
11 UIKit 0x33879364 -UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification + 168
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x36a12252 _dispatch_source_invoke + 510
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x36a0fb1e _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 42
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x36a0fe64 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 152
15 CoreFoundation 0x30e9c2a6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1262
16 CoreFoundation 0x30e1f49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
17 CoreFoundation 0x30e1f366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
18 GraphicsServices 0x33fb6432 GSEventRunModal + 130
19 UIKit 0x336f5e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
20 MyApp 0x00004818 main (main.m:16)
21 MyApp 0x000023b4 0x1000 + 5044
```

I checked and there are almost no memory leaks, e.g. when testing the app for an hour the total memory leaked was around 2-3Kb caused by some string-copying libraries. So I don't believe this is caused by the application. I guess that when the phone is not restarted for some time there are applications running in the background and when using Facebook SDK the memory becomes a problem and the system tries to recover the memory from random applications, including my application.

My question is, how can I prevent this crash from happening? How should I handle unloadViewForced on a view controller to make the app more robust in low-memory conditions? And lastly, am I right that this crashlog suggests the crash occurred because the system tried to free memory and my application didn't handle it properly?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this crash also occur when you run it in the simulator and use the "Simulate Memory Warning" menu item?

Comment: Didn't try, didn't know about this feature. Will try to find out. Thanks for this hint.

Comment: No, it doesn't :( We don't handle didReceiveMemoryWarning anywhere in the application. Clicking that option in menu on the simulator only prints a message on the console and does nothing apart from that.

Comment: I just recalled how to use that feature properly. You need to make sure that the active view controller is not the view controller with which you're having the crash. Make sure a different view controller is active, then use the menu item. The non active view controllers will then be asked to release memory.

Comment: Thanks, what 'menu item' you have in mind? It's hard to say in which controller exactly the crash occurred because LTBaseViewController is a base class for all our controllers. So the crashlog doesn't tell which controller exactly crashed. I assumed it was the top one, but you're right that it could have been any of the underneath controllers on the stack.

Comment: The previously mentioned "Simulate Memory Warning" menu item in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is most likely happening is that one of the objects being referred to and probably being released by `LTBaseViewController viewDidUnload` method is being doubly released. In fact, since the backtrace indicates that the crash is happing on line 145 of LTBaseViewController.m you should be able to quickly see which object is the culprit.

Comment: Forgot to mention that memory in the application is managed by ARC. So there is no manual releasing of objects. Also, I don't believe the number that is on the right to the function is the line. E.g. there is no viewDidUnload in LTBaseViewController in my code so it is calling the parent implementation. This is offset in bytes from the beginning of the function. I would need to compile to assembler with interleaved code instructions to find out at which line the problem happened but I am not sure how do that on a MAC.

Comment: What is on line 145 of LTBaseViewController.m? (Not LTBaseTableViewController.m).

Comment: The closing clause '}' of method viewWillAppear.

Comment: Look at this line: 21 MyApp 0x000023b4 0x1000 + 5044
This of course doesn't mean that the crash happened at line 5044 of the MyApp source code. It does, however, tell that it happened at offset 5044 bytes from the address where the app was loaded into memory.

Comment: If you look at the end of the stack trace line it says `LTBaseViewController.m:145`. That is what indicates the problem is occurring at line 145 of 'LTBaseViewController.m'. (However, if the source code has changed since the stack trace was generated they can be different.)

Comment: ThomasW again, the value 145 is not the line number but offset in bytes from the beginning of the method in memory!!!

Comment: The usual meaning of `foo.m:123` is a reference to line 123 of file `foo.m` while a offset is represented as + offset. You can see this by creating a test crash case by doing something like releasing an object you just created and calling one of its methods on iOS 4.x, then using `bt` in the debugger.

Comment: OK, I might have been wrong then. I didn't not noticed it as the sources have changed since the crash occurred. I would need to sync to that specific version to verify that it did crash in that specific line. Thanks for help.

Comment: Amiramix is the bug eventually solved? It seems that you accepted the answer, but from the conversation I can't tell what was the crash reason. I have a similar issue: ARC project, no manual release, but crashed when one view controller is receiving memory warning and unloading views.

Comment: @BaoLei Why don't you write up your problem?